# Problema al pasar el valor de un input por id a una función

Tags: javascript, jquery

En la siguiente tabla está formada por un input y un checkbox, de modo que cuando se pulsa el checkbox, el input se habilita para escribir. El valor que se introduce en el input quiero mandarselo a la función contador() que aparace más abajo.

Tabla:

```
<table class="table  table-hover">
   <thead >
      <tr>
       <th>
        Cantidad
      </th>
      <th>
        Incluir
      </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tab_logic">
    @foreach($alimentos as $a)
     <?php
       $i=uniqid();
       $cantidadid='cantidad'.$i;
     ?>
     <tr>
         <td   name="alimentos">
         <input id="{{'alimento'.$i}}" disabled type="hidden" name="alimentos[]"   value="{{$a->id}}"/>
         </td>
         <td  name="cantidad"  >
          <input id="{{'cantidad'.$i}}" disabled  type="int" name='cantidad[]'/>
          </td>
         <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="" onclick="contador(this,'{{$a->kcal}}','kcallds','{{$cantidadid}}')">
         </td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

El problema es que el console.log() me devuelve 'NaN' y además, aparece antes de que haya terminado de escribir en el input.

Función:

```
caloriasT={};

function contador(checkbox,kcal,nombre,cantidad) {
   var cant;
    if (typeof caloriasT[nombre] === 'undefined') {
        caloriasT[nombre] = 0;
    }else if(typeof cant === 'undefined') {
        cant=0;
    }
    cant=$('#'+cantidad).val();
    cant=parseFloat(cant);
    console.log('Cantidad:'+cant);

    var sum=parseFloat(kcal);


    if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
        caloriasT[nombre]+=sum;
    }else{
        caloriasT[nombre]-=sum;
    }
    $("#"+nombre).html(Math.abs(caloriasT[nombre]).toFixed(2));
}
```

¿Podrían ayudarme? 
Muchas gracias

Comment: El tipo de dato que envias no corresponde:  Not-A-Number (No es Un Número).

Comment: Primero as lo siguiente, ni bien abres tu fincion : console.log(checkbox);console.log(kcal);console.log(nombre);console.log(cantidad)

Comment: Me devuelve lo siguiente: 1- <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="" onclick="cambiarEstado(this,'alimento595a78f1c24e1','dia_semana595a78f1c24e1','momento595a78f1c24e1','cantidad595a78f1c24e1','comentario595a78f1c24e1');
                                                                contador(this,'92.2','kcallds','cantidad595a78f1c24e1');contadorP(this,'7','plds');contadorG(this,'3.2','glds');contadorH(this,'9.6','hlds')">    2- 92. 3- kcallds 3-cantidad595a78f1c24e1

Comment: En el 1- aparece mas informacion de la llamada que yo simplifique en la pregunta porque no era relevante

Comment: No pongas código en los comentarios, mejor edita la pregunta.